# Vagrant homestead box keeps crashing and exiting

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

My box just keeps freezing and chucking me out of ssh, is there any debug and log info that will help guide me as to why, plus I have installed the latest update, so i am confused. if I host many test sites on a box, and if they are active but not used, would this be why the server is overloading and just crashing? Any help here would be grandly helpful.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so please post a solution. Having a similar issue with Homestead 3.0 and pre update I never had any. I am now troubleshooting

Comment: No i did not resolve, I believe it was to do with php but I still came no closer.